# Strange bechaviour of my program with QFileDialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have created Qt window application in MS VS2010 using master and place some code in constructor of class of my window. Here is.

```
MyBug::MyBug(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QFileDialog fd;
    QString StackPath = fd.getExistingDirectory();
    std::vector<int> v;
    const int N=125000000;
    try
    {
        if (v.max_size()>N)
            v.resize(N);
    }catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText(e.what());
        msgBox.exec();
    }
}
```

When I’m trying to resize array I'm getting bad allocation exception. It obviously, that I'm trying to allocate less items than it's possible. However, when allocating as 10 times less as it was no one exception happened. It also depends on behavior of QFileDialog. If the dialog was closed down without choosing directory, resize procedure works successfully. Is there a bug in QFileDialog, and why I cannot resize my vector? How to resolve it? 
The OS I using is Windows 64, Qt version is 4.8.4, Target platform in VS2010 is Win32.

Comment: `125000000*sizeof(int) = 0.5` Gigabytes, I'm not surprised that a win32 application can't find a free area as big as 1/8th of it's addressable address space depending on previous allocations, why do you need such a large N?

Comment: It is not a bug of file dialog. You should understand, how memory is allocated at Win32. You have such problems because of memory fragmentation (possible)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to open a modal dialog (QFileDialog) while your main window is constructing. Let the main window finish construction, than open QFileDialog.

Comment: And why it dipends on QFolderDialog. It works OK if when dialog is unused. Moreover, I can also put another vector and allocate the same saze.

Comment: ok. I got it. Anyway I should not try to allocate a such big piece of memory. The reason of crash is memory fragmentation and file dialog just facilitate it allocating its own memory. Vector doesn't care about it and max_size always 2^30-1 for vector of integers in Win32